# Using Sub-Directory within install-time asset delivery in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, android-assets

I am trying to implement Play Asset Delivery for my Flutter app using package named **FlutterPlayAssetDelivery**. The basic implementation (of install-time delivery) is done. My folder structure looks something like this:
assets:

1. reset.png
2. fu(folder)

Now there is a file under folder 'fu' stated as:
fu\logo.png
now when i try to access assets inside 'fu' folder inside, it fails to access the assets at path:
fu/logo.png

P.S I am using the bundletool to test asset delivery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, the play asset delivery doesn't support any directory based organization. Thus, in order to access your files correctly, you must implement a different logic to organize the files inside the assetpack.

For instance, Suppose the avatar image files organization logic is:

```
Avatar/image1.jpg
```

in order to store a group of avatar images inside asset-packs, you can organize the file by renaming it as:

```
Avatar-image1.jpg
```